# How to pass parameters to admin_notices?

Tags: admin, actions, notices

So there is the following case.

I need to display a name inside of `admin_notices`.

```
class MyPlugin_Admin {
    public static function render_admin_notice() {
        echo $name . ' has been upgraded.';
    }
}

add_action( 'admin_notices', array( 'MyPlugin_Admin', 'render_admin_notice' ) );
```

How to populate `$name`?

I thougth of following solutions:

No. 1:

```
class MyPlugin_Admin {

    public static $name;

    public static function render_admin_notice() {
        echo self::$name . ' has been upgraded.';
    }
}

MyPlugin_Admin::$name = 'John Doe';

add_action( 'admin_notices', array( 'MyPlugin_Admin', 'render_admin_notice' ) );
```

No. 2:

```
$name = 'John Doe';

add_action('admin_notices', function() use ($name){ 
    echo $name . ' has been upgraded.'; 
});
```

I don't like both somehow, since No. 1 requires `$name` to be populate `class` wide and therefor might lead to confusion and No. 2 requires at least PHP 5.3.

Comment: Could you elaborate on *why* you need to pass a variable? Perhaps explain what you are ultimately trying to do (it will help us determine the best solution - it might even be the case that you're looking at this from the wrong angle!)

Comment: I need to display a success message on top of the page. The message needs to be personalized e.g. John Doe has been promoted. How do I pass the name into the function which is registered on the admin_notices hook.

Comment: Downvoted, PHP 5.5 will finally be EOL'ed in July, so I cannot see what your problem actually is here. Approach 2 solves the issue, is valid, stick with it and go with it.

Comment: As someone that released by mistake an update to a relatively popular plugin that broke on 5.2, I am willing to testify that the uproar was much smaller then might have been expected and we ended with changing the FAQ instead of changing the code. My conclusion is that either the people on 5.2 just don't upgrade at all, or upgrade the php is so easy they don't bother to complain. just my 2 cents

Comment: @PieterGoosen Your argumentation is not really worth a downvote. I agree with you that not using No. 2 because of the backwards compatibility issues it might produce is not always a good point, but still sometimes people care.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think a better implementation would be a "message" class e.g.:

```
class WPSE_224485_Message {
    private $_message;

    function __construct( $message ) {
        $this->_message = $message;

        add_action( 'admin_notices', array( $this, 'render' ) );
    }

    function render() {
        printf( '<div class="updated">%s</div>', $this->_message );
    }
}
```

This allows you to instantiate the message at any time prior to rendering:

```
if ( $done ) {
    new WPSE_224485_Message( "$name has been upgraded." );
}
```

Comment: That's a nice idea actually!

Comment: I've implemented it now: [class-qwall-notice.php](https://github.com/4ley/querywall/blob/master/core/class-qwall-notice.php) and that's how it gets called [class-qwall-core.php#L85](https://github.com/4ley/querywall/blob/master/core/class-qwall-core.php#L85)

Comment: Lookin' good :)

Comment: Bloody great idea, didn't cross my mind to do it this way :)

Answer (score 0):

Can be done much more straight forward:

```
$message = $name . ' has been upgraded.';

add_settings_error( 'my_admin_notice', 'my_admin_notice', $message, 'updated' );
```

Read more on https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_settings_error/

Comment: The problem with this that this function is not for this purpose. It's definition says: "Part of the Settings API. Use this to show messages to users about settings validation problems, missing settings or anything else." So this is related to Settings API. Generally a good habit to avoid using functions/hooks, etc. for out-of-their-scope issues, for other than they been designed for. (for example this function's name can be misleading for other developers.) Cheers

Comment: Hi Viktor thanks for the feedback :) Who said the Settings API is not for plugins? It is in fact the recommended way of handling plugin settings since a long time. I agree add_settings_error is a confusing name but the last parameter $type clearly shows that it is also intended to handle 'success', 'warning' and 'info' messages, not only 'error'...